# How do I change "city" to "suburb" when customers are checking out?

Tags: checkout

I want to change the "city" section to "suburb" please. how do I do that?

Comment: do you want to change `city` to `text` ?

Comment: Do You want to change only the label of that field?

Comment: Anyone explain, what is mean "suburb", may i know what is the suburb of Victoria, Australia?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Did you change that?